# windows PATH variable ignore version number

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

Since forever I have hardcoded environment path variables on windows, or used some script to find a path to an executable with a regex.  Is there a mechanism for adding a location to the PATH environment variable that ignores version numbers on Windows 10?

For example, say I want to add `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\x64"` to my path, but I know the version number (3.2.3) will be changing quite often.  Is there a way to do the equivalent of the following that would ignore anything between "C:\Program Files\R\R" and "\bin\x64"?

So, the result would be something like

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\x64
```

that could account for changing version number?

Comment: `set RVERSION=R-3.2.3` followed by `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\R\%RVERSION%\bin\x64` might do the trick. Stick that in a batch file you use to start `R`

Comment: You could do what is done in Linux: put `C:\Program Files\R\R-current\bin\x64` in `PATH`, then create `C:\Program Files\R\R-current` as a link to `C:\Program Files\R\R-R-3.2.3`, or whichever version you want to use.

Comment: @afh Good idea, but doesn't easily allow switching between different versions.

Comment: @DavidPostill - It's just the deletion and re-creation of the link, which I think is easier than changing an environment variable, which would mean editing a start-up file, though that is certainly another option. A fixed path could be added to to Windows environment and become global.

Comment: Thanks guys, @AFH, that sound's like it will work great.  I'll accept it if you are inclined to add an answer.  Would you use `mklink /D` on windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Linux handles different revisions is through links, and the same technique can be used on Windows. You can create a link to the current revision, eg:

```
mklink /j "C:\Program Files\R\R-current" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3"
```

Now you can add `C:\Program Files\R\R-current` to your path, either in a start-up file or, more permanently, in the Windows `PATH` settings. Whenever you want to change revisions simply enter:

```
rd "C:\Program Files\R\R-current"
mklink /j "C:\Program Files\R\R-current" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4"
```

You can obviously put these commands in a batch file with the revision code as a parameter.

Note that I have used `mklink /j` instead of `/d` because on Windows 10 I need administrative rights for `/d`, and because a junction behaves more rationally on remote file access, though for local use either could be used.